# How to add Entitlement.plist in xCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I am using the Xcode 4.2. I did not able to see any method to add Entitlements.plist in this version. So how can i do add that file in my project since i need to install my app on iPhone.

Comment: if you instal app from your xcode 4.2 no need of entitlements file.you need to modify build settings entitlements as nil.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Select the target in your project and scroll down. You'll see the option to add a custom entitlement.

[image]

For creating a new entitlement, just create a new plist file from new file menu item. Change it's type to iPhone entitlements as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Vin but how can i remove the existing and create new entitlement file from project like older xCode versions using Create New file and then add new entitlements

Comment: I have the same issue and I tried to do that but when I check the box Enable Entitlements, xcode creates a .entitlements file (not a .plist) is that normal? And I don't have the same contextual menu as you when I right-click on my Entitlements.plist = > I can't choose the property list type. What should I do? Is that true we don't need the entitlements file anymore in xcode 4.2 ?

Comment: you don't need and entitlement file anymore until you are doing something with iCloud.

Comment: When you check "Entitlements" a new entitlement file is automatically created and added to the project using the default of the project name.

Comment: creating a new plist, and giving it the extension ".entitlements" works.  You'll need to fill it in with the appropriate dictionary items, but XCode recognizes it as an entitlements file.