# Ad Hoc Distribution on XCode 4.2.1 - entitlements

Tags: xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, code-signing-entitlements

I am trying to build my app for ad hoc distribution (on TestFlight).  I have read through all instructions and done lots of web searching.  My problem is with how to create entitlements.plist on Xcode 4.2.1

All instructions say go to New File, then select entitlements under code signing.  This option is not available in 4.2.1 and I cannot work out how else to do it.  I can build the ipa but it won't install properly on anybody's device and I am pretty sure the entitlements issue is causing the problem.

This is my first app for distribution so I have no experience in doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: instructions with screenshots on this thread stackoverflow.com/questions/8547471/how-to-add-entitlement-plist-in-xcode-4-2/8548008#8548008

Comment: lazy link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547471/how-to-add-entitlement-plist-in-xcode-4-2/8548008#854800

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the summary of your target, scroll down and activate entitlements.

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need an entitlements file unless you are doing special stuff like iCloud - see https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG31

Comment: ...and TestFlight, apparently. I had the same issue as the OP, and I found that adding Entitlements.plist worked, although I don't understand why.