# How can I add an entitlements file to an XCode 4.5 project?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ad Hoc Distribution on XCode 4.2.1 - entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586988/ad-hoc-distribution-on-xcode-4-2-1-entitlements)

I'm using Xcode 4.5 and when I go to File > New > File ...  I don't see any option for entitlements files any more. How can I add one? Do I just create a blank plist? If so, what do I need to populate it with for an Ad Hoc release?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 4.5 you should do the following to get entitlements created (it's not via File > New  > File... any longer):

1. Select your project in the left hand file navigator
2. Select your target
3. Click on the "Summary" tab in the configuration area
4. Scroll to the bottom of the "Summary" section and you'll see an "Entitlements" section (you might need to turn down the disclosure triangle next to Entitlements)
5. Click the checkbox for "Use Entitlements File" and give it a custom name if you want
6. Fill in any values you need there (you can edit the plist file manually too).

Do note, you don't need to do anything special for AdHoc builds with entitlements files any longer.

Answer (score 5):

`Entitlements.plist` is just a plist file generally with one key value pair (`get-task-allow`) under root (which is a dictionary, see the image below) so creating a normal plist file is just fine.

[image: Get Task Allow]

Also don't forget to point it to your Entitlements.plist in your target in Build Settings -> Code Signing Entitlements (if Xcode doesn't automatically set it)

[image: Build Settings]

Read more here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1710/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to files > New File > Entitlements file...something like this must be there.

Sorry I correct > use the property file as entitlements!

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or a comment?