# How to add an entitlements.plist in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I know it is very easy to add an entitlements in xcode 3.2.But my doubt is how we can add that in xcode 4.2.I know there is a section entitlements under the target summary tab.But can anybody help me to know how to add the file to our resources folder as we did in Xcode 3.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547471/how-to-add-entitlement-plist-in-xcode-4-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project "Your Project Name" that appears at the left of ur window(KNOWN AS PROJECT NAVIGATOR),and select 'Add Files to MyProject' option

Comment: i am talking abt adding the entitlements.plist to my project in Xcode 4.2 what is this?